# When you want to find out the reasons behind someone's reclusion

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, register

Imagine two friends who are talking about the reclusion that one of them is dealing with it. The one who is OK, wants to ask the other one what has caused him to live in that way during the couple of weeks / months ago. Does the sentence below work here? If yes, is it natural and if not how shall I  indicate such a thing to a native speaker?

> - What’s the reason **(behind your / for) your reclusion**?

Or perhaps:

> - **You've lived in reclusion** for several months. What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: **Imagine two friends ...**

Your sentences are grammatical but the tone of **reclusion** is clinical, not conversational.

> Why have you been a recluse for the past few months? What's going on?
>
> You've been living as a recluse for months. What's wrong?

Comment: In regular conversation, how about [*seclusion*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seclusion)?

Comment: Seclusion does not have the clinical tone of reclusion (as there is no such noun as [secluse]) so on that score it is OK, but seclusion is not reclusion and the two words are not perfectly interchangeable.  A person with an active social life may return to the seclusion of home, whereas a recluse never ventures out. To live in seclusion is to live hidden away, out of choice or necessity, whereas the recluse may be emotionally incapable of leaving his or her seclusion. Reclusion may not be volitional.

Comment: TRomano do you agree that we can substitute "recluse" with loner in colloquialism and friendly conversations?

Comment: @TRomano imagine Buddha who lived in reclusion for mystical and religious issues. Here, the word "reclusion" for mystical and somehow supernatural experiences can be used or it will indicate clinical tone to a native speaker?

Comment: @A-friend, **recluse** and **loner** are more-or-less synonyms. **Loner** is in a slightly informal register; **recluse** is in standard register. Both can be used in friendly conversations.  A recluse tends not to venture out in public, but a loner often does, while keeping his or her distance from others. A loner may sit alone and not join a group.

Comment: With monastic / religious reclusion, the word **reclusion** is still in a rather  formal register. There it is not clinical but academic in its tone. The word could be used in an academic study of the monastic life, for example. If you wish to avoid sounding like an academic, and were telling the story of Buddha to a lay audience, you would say that he *lived as a recluse*.

Comment: @TRomano The noun form is [*seclude*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seclude).

Comment: @TRomano how about it's adjective "reclusive"? Does it sound natural to say: "He lives as a reclusive / solitary" person? Do they mean the same? I would be really thankful if you confirm my taking. I guess these all mean the same. I mean your offered one and the sentence in my question here.